# Prettify a one-line JSON file

Tags: json, vim

I downloaded a 203775480 bytes (~200 MiB, exact size is important for a later error) JSON file which has all entries *all on one line*. Needless to say, my text editor (ViM) cannot efficiently navigate in it and I'm not able to understand anything from it. I'd like to prettify it. I tried to use `cat file.json | jq '.'`, `jq '.' file.json`, `cat file.json | python -m json.tool` but none worked. The former two commands print nothing on stdout while the latter says `Expecting object: line 1 column 203775480 (char 203775479)`.
I guess it's broken somewhere near the end, but of course I cannot understand where as I cannot even navigate it.

Have you got some other idea for prettifying it? (I've also tried `gg=G` in ViM: it did not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the file was indeed broken: I accidentally noticed a ']' at the beginning of the file so I struggled to go to the end of the file and added a ']' at the end (it took me maybe 5 minutes).

Then I've rerun `cat file.json | python -m json.tool` and it worked like a charm.